# Can I submit dictionary file to Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, dictionary

I have created a .dictionary file for the Dictionary.app in mac and I want to submit it to the Mac App Store. I'm curious, is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Where did the data in your dictionary come from?  Is it free for public use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't upload 'plugins / extentions' to the Mac App Store. Only full 'apps' will be approved for the mac app store. To create a mac app, you need a developer license to be able to publish your app through the Mac App Store.

Comment: You can flag this post as answered if this helped.